# unattended-upgrade breaks 21.04 raspbeery pi

Tags: upgrade, 21.04

New full install of ubuntu 21.04 Desktop (64 bit) on raspberrypi
Boots to desktop

Do nothing but wait because unattended-upgrades (on by default) is upgrading.
Unattended-upgrade finishes with request reboot to complete.

Reboot but no desktop (or terminal on monitor)

Repeat complete procedure but immediately
install ssh

Same result
Login using ssh.

Remove desktop & dependencies & configurations and reinstall desktop.
Reboot
Still no screen terminal.

Turn off replace SD card with known working installation (21.04)and boots fine.
But unattended upgrade is also on and without thinking I OK it because the upgrade is really small.

Same result, no desktop, no terminal. This one is fatal because no ssh
ctrl+Alt+Del resets and reboots so the system is running and the keyboard is working

Comment: You believe that unattended upgrades are crashing your system. Is it up-to-date?  Maybe it's just slow because you have a lot of pending updates and you aren't giving it enough time?  You can remove the `unattended-upgrades` package if you don't want to use it.  If you do that, you will need to periodically apply updates manually.

Comment: Unattended-updates is on by default. Cannot remove it till it finishes.

Comment: Unattended-updates NOT crashing the system, one of the updates cause the crash. only happened last few days

Comment: Put your SD card in a reader in a working system. Read the file `/var/log/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades.log`, and post the list of packages that were upgraded in your Question.

Comment: disabled gdm with sudo systemctl disable gdm.service, reboot comes up in terminal but has `error hdmi-audio-codec hdmi-audio-codec.2.auto : ASoC : error at snf_soc_dai_startup on i2s-hifi : -19`

Comment: /unattended-upgrades log has information that the upgrade list was out of date. I think this log was reset on reboot or sometime after.

Comment: which upgrade pkg contains effect hdmi-audio-codecs or is it configuration of gdm?

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully, the first thing you did was install ssh, so you can remotely login to your raspberrypi.
The offending packages is one of  `linux-headers-raspi,linux-image-raspi & linux-raspi`
The offending versions of these are `5.11.0.19.17`

Do a `sudo apt -a <pkg as above>` for each package.
Hopefully the list will show the version of each one installed and the previous version, which should be 5.11.0.1007.5

DO `sudo apt install linux-headers-raspi=5.11.0.1007.5 linux-image-raspi=5.11.0.1007.5 linux-raspi=5.11.0.1007.5`

You need to do them all at once because they are dependent on each other, then do a reboot (wait a few minutes before doing that)
Remotely login again.
You may have to do a `sudo systemctl stop gdm.service` , wait a little while then do a `sudo systemctl start gdm.service.`
Reboot once more and you should boot to the desktop.